# How to convert string "290416" in date format in php

Tags: php, string, date-format

I need to convert string value "290416" which is actually date but not in correct format. I need to change it in date format like 29/04/16.
please help.

Comment: [$date = `DateTime::createFromFormat( 'dmy', '290416' )->format( 'd/m/y' )`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)

Comment: @fusion3k you should post this as an answer - it's correct.

Comment: yeah it worked thanks a lot @fusion3k you can post as your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need it as a date but only in date format. Meaning you are not performing any date-functions on it but just displaying it as a date you could use

```
$str = '290416';
$arr = str_split($str, 2);
$date_string = $implode('/', $arr);
```

Comment: thanks it also worked. but 
$datet = DateTime::createFromFormat( 'dmy', '290416' )->format( 'd/m/y' ); 
also worked

Answer (score 0):

The most robust way will be to use [createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php), passing in your format and the string, and they you have a DateTime object and can do many things with it.

```
define('MY_DATE_INPUT_FORMAT', 'mdy');
define('MY_DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT', 'm/d/y');
$inputDateString = '042916';
$dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat(MY_DATE_INPUT_FORMAT, $inputDateString);
$outputString = $dateObj->format(MY_DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT);
```

This can also be done procedurally:

```
$date = date_create_from_format(MY_DATE_INPUT_FORMAT, $inputDateString);
echo date_format($date, MY_DATE_OUTPUT_FORMAT);
```